# How can I grant to the limited users to see the structure of mysql routines?

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant, mysql-routines

How can I grant somebody to see the structure of mysql routines?
The following command can be used to show the structure of routines:

```
show create function FUNCTION_NAME
```

or

```
show create procedure PROCEDURE_NAME
```

but It should be run by the user with `grant all` permission. **I don't want to give `grant all` to the user**. What is the exact grant I need or what is the alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html)

> To use either statement, you must be the user named in the routine DEFINER clause or have SELECT access to the mysql.proc table.

So granting `SELECT` to the `mysql.proc` table should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks so much @Nanne , your answer solves my problem. I had test the grant to `information_schema.ROUTINES` but It didn't work correctly. The limited user can not access to `ROUTINE_DEFINITION`. But the grant to `mysql.proc` solves my problem. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8.20+ you can use:

```
GRANT SHOW_ROUTINE ON . TO username
```

[MySQL 8 Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-routine)